# Alternative to Group_concat in MS SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have a simple query that does group concat very well in SQL workbench.

```
id hobby
 1 dance
 1 sing
 2 play
 2 sing
```

Expected output:

```
id hobby
1 dance,sing
2 play,sing
```

How can I get this output using MS SQL Server?

Comment: Starting from MS Sql Server 2017 you have [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql)

Comment: Yes, my version is SQL 2012